# How to code for segmented sieve ,given two interval?

Tags: c++14

I understood the Sieve of Eratosthenes clearly.But i am facing trouble in understanding segmented sieve.My question is that given two range

```
(a=b=10^8)
```

how to find the prime numbers between this two interval,where

```
b-a<=10^5)
```

Please help me to design the code.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link for a C++ implementation and explanation of the segmented sieve for  a single range n https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segmented-sieve/

For your case where you have range a to b with upper limit of 10^8 your max segment size will be sqrt(10^8) = 10,000 and where upper limit on the difference b-a is 10^5 you will have a maximum of 10 segments to process.

Take the algorithm from the link given and use your range b as the input n and calculate the base vector prime, then adjust the limits

```
 // Divide the range [0..n-1] in different segments 
// We have chosen segment size as sqrt(n). 
int low = limit; 
int high = 2*limit;
```

set low to the closest multiple of limit that is <= a and ignore any result in the output < a

This should solve your problem as presented.